# auto select radio button depending on condtion

Tags: javascript

I have 10 dropdowns (Field ID: Test 1-10), with the dropdown options of Yes/No

I have a radio button (Field ID: Result) which has the option of pass/fail.

I would like a javascript where the radio button option to auto select either pass/fail.

The radio button field will auto select pass if Yes is selected 4 or more times from the dropdowns.

Thank you
Joseph

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site. If you continue to ask poor quality and downvoted questions, you will get a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: That is a project brief, not a programming problem. Show us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer!

It must provide you an hint!

```
<label>yes</label><input type="radio" name="rad1" value="yes">
<label>no</label><input type="radio" name="rad1" value="no" >

<br>
<br>

<label>yes</label><input type="radio" name="rad2" value="yes" >
<label>no</label><input type="radio" name="rad2" value="no">

<br>
<br>


<label>yes</label><input type="radio" name="rad3" value="yes">
<label>no</label><input type="radio" name="rad3" value="no">



 var rad = document;

 var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(radios, function(radio) {
   radio.addEventListener('change', calculate);
});


    function calculate(){
    console.log('ss')
            var count = 0;
      var options = document.getElementsByName("rad1");
      if (options) {
          for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
              if (options[i].checked){
                   if(options[i].value=='yes'){
                                        count++;           
                   }
              }
          }
      }  

      var options = document.getElementsByName("rad2");
      if (options) {
          for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
              if (options[i].checked){
                   if(options[i].value=='yes'){
                                        count++;           
                   }
              }
          }
      } 

      var options = document.getElementsByName("rad3");
      if (options) {
          for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
              if (options[i].checked){
                   if(options[i].value=='yes'){
                                        count++;           
                   }
              }
          }
      } 

      if(count>2)
      {
         alert('count is 2 or more, paas this guy!'); 
      }

    }
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n0up17kb/2/